# How to keep localhost URL short in Mountain Lion

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion

I am using mac osx (mountain lion).
All the php, apache has been installed with no problem.

I create a simple landing page and i put in my Sites folder.
I can see the landing page when i enter `http://localhost/~dolmat/landing` (the landing page is in a folder named "landing")

But i dont like the `http://localhost/~dolmat/landing`
(I don't know why in osx mountain lion, you must run your localhost with ~username, how to avoid this?

So i setup virtual host, so this is what my vhosts.conf file is look like (located /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/dolmat/Sites/landing"
        ServerName landing.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my hosts file look like (located in /etc/hosts)

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       landing.dev
```

I restart Apache, what i want is when i use landing.dev it will show the landing page but it shows page not found. When i use landing.dev/~dolmat/landing then i can see the page.

Why? Why it must inlcude the ~dolmat/landing in the URL? I already point to the right DocumentRoot

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you include virtual hosting in your httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2/

The line looks like this:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I have feeling yours looks like this though

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

So just uncomment it and restart apache and you will be good hopefully